# Only send mails when changes are done in one specific worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to generate a code to fire push notifications to different email addresses based on the location of the occured changes (current worksheet among other worksheets within the same spreadsheet). As an example, I could have the worksheets called "firstsheet" and "secondsheet". Unfortunately, I have no coding experience and all I found was the following:

```
function 1() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
if (ss.getName() == "firstsheet") return;
MailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress1","Title","Content");

}
function 2() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
if (ss.getName() == "secondsheet") return;
MailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress2","Title","Content");

}
```

But this leads to an email to both addresses any time, a change occurs in both worksheets, meaning, there is no separation at all. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

have a look, let me know if you need any clarifications/ this doesn't solve your issue.

```
function change_made_to_sheet(event_object) {
    var sheet = event_object.range.getSheet(); // Get the sheet in which changes have been made
    if (sheet.getName() == "firstsheet") { // Check if the sheet name is matching with firstsheet
        // If the sheet name matched then execute this block when the sheet
        MailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress1","Title","Content"); // Send email
    } else if (sheet.getName() == "secondsheet") { // Check if sheet name matches secondsheet
        // If matched then execute this block
        MailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress2","Title2","Content2"); // Send email
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Thank you for your answer! There is still an error in line 2, it says "range can't be read". Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: `event_object` is available only when this function is triggered by a trigger and not when executed manually.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I have editet to different triggers, but it still does not work properly. In fact, no email is sent at all. What do I have to do? The mails should be sent triggered by any changements done in the specific worksheet. Thank you for your advises! :)

Comment: First you make sure your triggers are configured correctly.
Design a simple function to send email to you. Create trigger for that.
Once you make that working then use condition inside that to check for sheet name and send email accordingly.

Comment: I did the following:
1. Setup the basic function as you said:

function emailExample(event_object) {
  
  var sheet = event_object.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "changelog") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
    'emailaddress1',
    'topic',
    'text'
    );}
2. Setup of a trigger, that fires with any changement in the spreadsheet (I tested and it worked out)

Comment: 3. Implement your code above leading to:

function emailExample(event_object) {
  
  var sheet = event_object.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "changelog") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
    'emailadress1',
    'topic',
    'text'
  );
    
    } else if (sheet.getName() == "translationdecisions") {
      MailApp.sendEmail(
    'emailadress2',
    'topic',
    'text'
  );
    }}